# Применение установленных шрифтов (AddFontResource) без перезагрузки Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, шрифты

Добрый день, уважаемые форумчане!

Имеется куча шрифтов (.ttf, .otf). Программно их устанавливаю:

- копирую файлы в `Windows\Fonts`,
- прописываю в реестр значения,
- регистрирую через `AddFontResource`.

Однако шрифты в системе появляются только после перезагрузки Windows. Можно как-то сделать без перезагрузки?

**P. S.:** `WM_FONTCHANGE` рассылаю. Видимо, этого недостаточно. Надо ещё какую-то WinAPI-шную функцию вызвать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение.

Я в **AddFontResource** регистрировал *исходный* файл.

Если регистрировать файл из каталога **Windows\Fonts**, то все применяется сразу.